# Changing information in file to print

Tags: python, file, io

I have code that takes the information from a file and prints out the same design, but with different characters. For examplem, A.txt has a text file with the image "A" made out of * and : but i need it to get printed using upper and lower case 'a'

```
import os


def main():

    # relative path to the folder where you unzipped the ASCII art files
    #folder = "stars"
    # or use an absolute path to the folder. example:
    folder = r"C:\Users\sarah\Documents\a CPS 111\Bonus PA\stars\stars"

    # os.listdir(folder) returns a list of files in folder
    file_list = os.listdir(folder)
    letter_art = {}

    word = str(input("Please input a letter: "))  
    word = word.upper()

    for fname in file_list:

        letter_extension_list = fname.split(".")

    for letter in word:
        key = letter
        value = letter_extension_list[1]
        value = "%s."%(key) + value 
        letter_art[key] = value 

        fname = "\\".join([folder, value])
        print(fname)

        infile = open(fname)

        for line in infile.readlines:
            line = line.split()
            if "*" in line:
                print(word.upper())
            else:
                print(word.lower())



    infile.close()



main()
```

right now my error is

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

Comment: I hope you are doing readlines on file content. Remove read() method and invoke readlines method like readlines().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `infile = open(fname).read()` to `infile = open(fname)`

You cannot `readlines()` from string.

`TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable`: you should add `()` after the builtin method `readlines`, basically you are trying to iterate over the return of this method instead of the method itself.

Also remove `line = line.split()` if you are trying to check if `*` is in the string, `line.split()` will turn `line` into `[line]`

Comment: i changed it to `infile = open(fname)` and now the error is `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in infile.readlines:
```

readlines is a function, and can not be iterated. a function can be called by caller and return values. so you just need to call the function and iterate over it's return values like this:

```
for line in infile.readlines():
    pass
```